# Postgresql 12 - ddluser and dmluser for same schema dml permission denied on tables

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-12, dml

I have created a postgres 12  instance and executed the below command sequence:

```
psql --host localhost -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb"
psql --host localhost -U postgres -d mydb -f /tmp/createdb.sql
```

The need is to create tables with ddluser and the dmluser can manipulate(insert/select/delete) the contents of the tables that ddluser will create.

The contents of `/tmp/createdb.sql` are the following:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS ddluser;
DROP USER IF EXISTS dmluser;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS ddlrole;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS dmlrole;
CREATE USER ddluser WITH PASSWORD '1234';
CREATE USER dmluser WITH PASSWORD '1234';
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE mydb FROM PUBLIC;
CREATE ROLE ddlrole;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO ddlrole;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema TO ddlrole;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema FROM ddlrole;
GRANT ddlrole TO ddluser;
CREATE ROLE dmlrole;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO dmlrole;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO dmlrole;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO dmlrole;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO dmlrole;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema TO dmlrole;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO dmlrole;
GRANT dmlrole TO dmluser;
```

The table I create for example is the below:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.accounts (
user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    last_login TIMESTAMP );
```

Output is:

```
mydb=> select * from myschema.accounts;
ERROR:  permission denied for table accounts
mydb=> exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- the database user running the commands in `/tmp/createdb.sql` is a superuser (let's say it's `postgres`)
- the database user running the `CREATE TABLE` later is `ddluser`

Your expectation is probably that this command run by the superuser:
`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO dmlrole;`
will make every object created in `myschema` have these permissions.

But in fact only objects created by `postgres` would be affected, because, according to the [documentation for ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html):

> **You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.**

(*yourself* in this context means of course the current db user)

The simplest solution is to switch temporarily to `ddlrole` in the creation script.

```
[... statements run by the superuser...]

SET ROLE ddlrole;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO dmlrole;
    
RESET ROLE;

[... rest of statements run by the superuser...]
```

Then the tables created in the future in `myschema` will have these permissions when they're created by a member of `ddlrole`.

Comment: it did not worked with set/reset but with altering default privilegges on ddluser. it seems that does not inherit from role :/ 
`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER ddluser IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO dmlrole;`